# How can we use single line array in below VBScript?

Tags: vbscript

```
'how can we use all values str1,str2 under str1

path = "D:\verify\files\"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set directory = fso.GetFolder(path).Files

For Each file In directory
    If file.Attributes = "32" Then
        Dim sSearchString1, sSearchString2, sSearchString3, sSearchString4, extension

        sSearchString1 = "<IDNew>511</IDNew>"
        sSearchString2 = "<Name>nielle</Name>"
        sSearchString3 = " <IDNew>643</IDNew>"
        sSearchString4 = "<Name>ase</Name>"

        extension = "xml"

        Set oFolder = fso.GetFolder(dir)

        For Each fil In oFolder.Files
            Set oFile = fso.OpenTextFile(fil.Path, ForReading) 
            strName1 = fso.GetFileName(fil)    

            sReadAll = oFile.ReadAll
            oFile.Close

            If InStr(sReadAll, sSearchString1) > 0 Or _
                    InStr(sReadAll, sSearchString2) > 0 Or _
                    InStr(sReadAll, sSearchString3) > 0 Or _
                    InStr(sReadAll, sSearchString4) > 0 Then
                count = count+1
                fso.CopyFile fil.Path, StrDestinationLocation

                cap12 = " Backup Success"
                strContent = "" & Date & Space(1) & sms & Space(1) & cap12 & Space(2) & strName1
                Set objLogs = FSO.OpenTextFile(strFileName1, ForAppending, True)
                objLogs.WriteLine(strContent)
                objLogs.Close
            End If
```

Comment: What "single line array"? What is `str1`? Actually, what is your question in the first place?

Comment: Instead of this 4 string values in one string
sSearchString1 = "511"

sSearchString2 = "nielle"

sSearchString3 = " 643"

sSearchString4 = "ase" I want to use like this
 all values in sSearchString1="511","nielle","643","ase"

Comment: `sSearchString1 = Array("511", "nielle", ...)`?

Comment: After above change I can remove this InStr(sReadAll, sSearchString2) > 0 Or _ InStr(sReadAll, sSearchString3) > 0 Or _ InStr(sReadAll, sSearchString4) > 0

Comment: That depends on what you expect your code to do.

Comment: I am excepting code to do if any one value match for this ssearchstring1=array("511","nielle",.....) Copy file to different folder

Answer (score 1):

You may want to put your check in a function like this:

```
Function ContainsAny(txt, arr)
    ContainsAny = False
    For Each str In arr
        If InStr(txt, str) > 0 Then
            ContainsAny = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

so you can test your input like this:

```
sSeachString1 = Array("511", "nielle", ...)

For Each fil In oFolder.Files
    sReadAll = fso.OpenTextFile(fil.Path, ForReading).ReadAll

    If ContainsAny(sReadAll, sSearchString1) Then
        '...
        'copy file
        '...
    End If
Next
```

Comment: its not working                                                                                                                           sSeachString1 = Array("511", "nielle", ...)

For Each fil In oFolder.Files
    sReadAll = fso.OpenTextFile(fil.Path, ForReading).ReadAll

    If ContainsAny(sReadAll, sSearchString1) Then
        '...
        'copy file
        '...
    End If
Next

Comment: @SAH I'm not going to provide you with a turnkey solution, if that's what you expected. You need to integrate the code snippets from my answer with the rest of your code. If you're unable to do that I recommend finding a VBScript tutorial or hiring someone who actually knows VBScript.